# How do you say "July 29, 1958" in American English? Is it "July twenty ninth, nineteen fifty eight" or "July the twenty ninth, nineteen fifty eight"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, reading-aloud, dates

Same question for this date: October 1, 1958

Is it "october first, nineteen fifty eight" or "october the first, nineteen fifty eight"?

Do we say "the" between the month and the day number?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference -- I hear both.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6747/9161

Comment: Either, but the first is most common in my experience (as a native English speaker in the U.S.)

Answer (score 3):

The standard way for an American to speak the date represented by *October 1, 1958* is *October first, nineteen fifty-eight*, as exemplified in Franklin Roosevelt's speech [declaring war on Japan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK8gYGg0dkE) following the attack on Pearl Harbor:

> Yesterday, December seventh, nineteen forty-one, a date which will live in infamy …

There are numerous variations, however. *October the first, nineteen fifty-eight* would  neither be incorrect nor particularly unusual, nor particularly regional. A different president, [announcing a different war](http://edition.cnn.com/2001/US/09/20/gen.bush.transcript/), addressed Congress with

> On September the eleventh, enemies of freedom committed an act of war …

but I would note that in every transcript, the *the* is always deliberately inserted— *September the 11th* or *September the eleventh*— it is not unconsciously "inserted" by the reader, and must be explicitly mentioned to make an accurate transcript.

Another variation would be *October first, nineteen hundred and fifty-eight*, though this is rarer and usually done for rhetorical effect, to make the date longer and sound more ostentatious. To say *the first of October, nineteen fifty-eight* is also accepted, though most Americans would not read out a date printed as *October 1, 1958* in that way. This format feels heavier, perhaps because is spoken and printed this way in legal and other very formal documents:

> This agreement shall be effective at noon, Mountain Standard Time, on the 21st day of February, 2015
>
> Col. and Mrs. Robert Delarue request the honor of your presence at the marriage of their daughter Mary Elizabeth to John Anderson Connor, Saturday, the twelfth of June, twenty-eleven, at half past one in the afternoon.
>
> Now, therefore, I, Barack Obama, President of the United States of America … do hereby proclaim September 28, 2013, as National Hunting and Fishing Day…. In witness whereof, I have hereunto set my hand this twenty-seventh day of September, in the year of our Lord two thousand thirteen, and of the Independence of the United States of America the two hundred and thirty-eighth.

Slightly off topic, but I would note that while *[Fourth of July](http://www.usa.gov/Topics/Independence-Day.shtml)* is the commonest way to refer to Independence Day, when referring to the date and not the holiday, the usual rules apply: the recorded phone greeting for my bank might chirp

> Our offices will be closed from July second through July fourth for the Independence Day holiday

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for a serious formal oral presentation, would you recommend me to say “July twenty ninth” or “July the twenty ninth”?

Comment: @user50746 *July twenty ninth* is conventional everywhere; I myself would say *July the twenty-ninth* only for emphasis (e.g. if there were multiple dates in July, and I wanted to emphasize that I was referring to a different date) or rhetorical effect (e.g. to draw special attention to a date as the signifier of something momentous).

Comment: @choster 'Conventional *everywhere*'? Not in Australian English.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut The question and answer specifically ask about American English. So yes, conventional everywhere within the context of the question and the answer.

Comment: @choster Wow, somehow I completely missed the mention of 'American English' in the question, sorry!

Comment: Formally, I believe you only include "the" when excluding the year. So it would be "September the Eleventh" vs. "September Eleventh, Two-thousand One".

Comment: @Omegacron With some dates, the rhythm of speech may make it more natural to insert a *the*, but there is no rule about when it can or cannot be used.